# How do I add another footer menu?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am using the customizr theme on wordpress and I want to edit my footer menu. On the help page I found this php code. I put it in functions.php and it does work but I want to add another menu.

```
add_filter('tc_credits_display', 'my_custom_credits');
function my_custom_credits(){ 
$credits = '';
$newline_credits = '';
return '
<div class="span4 credits">
                <p> &middot; &copy; '.esc_attr( date( 'Y' ) ).' <a href="'.esc_url( home_url() ).'" title="'.esc_attr(get_bloginfo()).'" rel="bookmark">'.esc_attr(get_bloginfo()).'</a> &middot; '.($credits ? $credits : 'Designed by <a href="http://www.themesandco.com/">Themes &amp; Co</a>').' &middot;'.($newline_credits ? '<br />&middot; '.$newline_credits.' &middot;' : '').'</p>      </div>';
}
```

The 1st one is copyright, 2nd one is themes & co link, I want to add another one for terms of service.

```
'<a href="my website link">Terms of Service</a>').'
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

to add another menu you need to do two things first declare the menu in the themes function file like so:

```
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

Where register_my_menu can be whatever you want to call the function,  header-menu needs to be unique and match the following command.

Then:

`<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>`

to echo out the menu in the theme files...
please read this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus